# How can I check the user's network?

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask, wallets

I want to check the user's network.

How I can implement something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current chain with `ethereum.chainId`.

To listen to chainId changes, you can set up an event handler like this

```js
ethereum.on('chainChanged', (chainId) => {
    //logic for chain change
});
```

Answer (score 0):

returns Number: The network ID.

```
web3.eth.net.getId()
.then( netID => {
console.log(netID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        async function getChainID() {chainId = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_chainId' }).then(chainSymbol => { if (chainSymbol == 0x38) {
            //bsc network
         }else if(chainSymbol == 0x1){ 
            //eth network
         }
     });     
}
```